# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID ADDRESS Crash on iOS9 devices

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I've been trying to track down a crash on an app and no matter what I do, I cannot clear it. The crash only happens on iOS9 devices but I can't reproduce it. The reports I get are:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x20fdba66 objc_msgSend + 5
1  Foundation                     0x2205d6df __NSThreadPerformPerform + 386
2  CoreFoundation                 0x217f5dff 
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
3  CoreFoundation                 0x217f5981 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 344
4  CoreFoundation                 0x217f3d5b __CFRunLoopRun + 794
5  CoreFoundation                 0x21743229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
6  CoreFoundation                 0x21743015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
7  GraphicsServices               0x22d33ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
8  UIKit                          0x25e17189 UIApplicationMain + 144
9  MyApp                          0x63cd0 main (GameViewController.swift:18)
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x213eb873 (Missing)
```

and

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x21fdfa76 objc_msgSend + 21
1  Foundation                     0x230616df __NSThreadPerformPerform + 386
2  CoreFoundation                 0x227f9dff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
3  CoreFoundation                 0x227f9981 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 344
4  CoreFoundation                 0x227f7d5b __CFRunLoopRun + 794
5  CoreFoundation                 0x22747229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
6  CoreFoundation                 0x22747015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
7  GraphicsServices               0x23d37ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
8  UIKit                          0x26e1b189 UIApplicationMain + 144
9  MyApp                          0xa9cd0 main (GameViewController.swift:18)
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x223ef873 (Missing)
```

All very mysterious! There is no runInMode() in the code and I have dealt with the only mutable array in the script by joining to a string. I've tried profiling with instruments and nothing showed up.

What could be causing this crash that only intermittently happens on iOS9?

Comment: UPDATE: I ran Instruments again looking for leaks and it found over 1000 in the first launch of malloc 8 bytes then closes. All it is loading is a storyboard and there are no warnings. I couldn't get any more info on them however so I'm no further on.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I get a crash that only happens in an earlier OS version, it's because I'm using something that was introduced in a later OS version. My first check would be to see if you're using something that perhaps was added after 9.0 keeping in mind things could have been added in 9.1, 9.2, etc.  In your tests, are using literally the 9.0 simulator, or a higher 9.x simulator?  Test with the 9.0 to make sure, as that would instantly test this possibility.

Comment: I just checked and the majority crash version is 9.3.5, which I think is the latest.

Comment: Bummer, that would have been an easy win.

Comment: Tell me about it - I'm on my 35th build :/